# Querying a large turtle file

Tags: python, performance, sparql, rdflib, turtle-rdf

I have a turtle file with more than 70 millions lines which I query using a python script, the thing is that the execution takes too long.

Here is an example of what I tried to do:

```
import rdflib
import rdfextras
rdfextras.registerplugins() 

g=rdflib.Graph()
g.parse("my_file.ttl", format='turtle')
results = g.query("""
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX bk:  <http://www.ondex.org/bioknet/terms/>
    SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?nbr_of_genes)
    WHERE {
    ?gene rdf:type bk:Gene.
    }
""")
```

I took a sample of 1 million lines from the original file and this simple query took 76 seconds to execute !

Is there a faster way to query the file ?

Comment: If you use variables in place of the wild card, it's normally a bit faster. Then, I imagine your queries are more complicated than this. If you check the patterns separately for number of results, then reoreding them might help.

Comment: 1. Measure loading and querying time separately. 2. Use full-fledged triplestore instead of RDFLib. 3. Try to count [subjects()](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/rdflib/graph.html#Graph.subjects) not using SPARQL.

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov It's slightly faster using variables (72 sec) but as you said, this query is the simplest one, so executing more complicated queries will be much slower.

Comment: @StanislavKralin 1. Loading took 98% of the execution time. 2. Please excuse my lack of knowledge, what do you mean by "full-fledged triplestore" ? 3. I'll try that. Thank you

Comment: Thus, the problem is to load triples only once and then querying them. An example of full-fledged triplestore is Virtuoso, which is used in endpoint from your previous question. Try to install Virtuoso locally.

Comment: That's the only useful answer...use a proper triple store to avoid loading the data every time and in addition benefit from index structures.

Comment: Or possibly you could try rdflib persistent stores, e.g. sleepycat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your Turtle file into a proper RDF Triple or Quad Store, and naturally benefit from the DBMS features and functionality.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did, I installed virtuoso triplestore and used the local endpoint to query the DB.